# Convert CURL to Python rest apt call

Tags: python, json, jenkins

I'm trying to post via api call in Jenkins, following CURL commands works and parameters are applied correctly.

```
curl -X POST -v http://localhost:8080/job/DNS_Tool_v1/build --user user01:1231121212121212121212 --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name": "registration_action","value": "DDNS_only"},{"name": "Note:", "value": "test01"},{"name": "entries","value": "add, hostname01.local.example.com, 192.168.1.1/24\nremove, hostname01.local.example.com, 192.168.1.1/24\n" }]}'
```

But some reason with requests POST doesn't dump the value from the dict. What's wrong with this code? Any idea? Thank you.

PYTHON CODE:

```py
params = {'parameter': [{"name": "registration_action", "value": "DDNS_only"}, \
          {"name": "Note:", "value": "test01"}, \
          {"name": "entries","value": "add, hostname01.local.example.com, 192.168.1.1/24\nremove, hostname01.local.example.com, 192.168.1.1/24\n" }]}

data = {'json': json.dumps(params)}
job_url = "http://{0}:{1}@{2}/job/{3}/{4}".format(user, pswd, jenkins_host, jenkins_job, jenking_action)
# output of job_url >> http://user01:1231121212121212121212@localhost:8080/job/DNS_Tool_v1/build
response = requests.post(job_url,headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},data=data)
```

OUTPUT Response I get: `<Response [201]>` but When I see the job created, no parameters passed in.

UPDATE CODE, STILL ERROR:

```
url = "http://localhost:8080"    
auth = (user, pswd)
crumb_data = requests.get("{0}/crumbIssuer/api/json".format(url),auth = auth,headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, verify=False)
print(crumb_data.content)
print(crumb_data.json()['crumb'])
job_url = "http://{0}:{1}@localhost:8080/buildWithParameters".format(user, pswd)
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Jenkins-Crumb':crumb_data.json()['crumb']}
response = requests.post(job_url,headers=headers, json=params, verify=False)
print(response.text.encode('UTF-8'))
```

ERROR

```
b'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /job/coreinfra/job/prod/job/DNStool/job/DDNS_Tool_v1/buildWithParameters. Reason:\n<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: What version of the `requests` package are you using?

Comment: Can you try without the `json.dumps()`?

Comment: remove the 'json' key from your data, use either `data=json.dumps(params)` or `json=params` in your request

Comment: requests version: 2.22.0
Tried without json.dumps >> as soon as I ran, I get error 
`
****************
b'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /job/DDNS_Tool_v1/build. Reason:\n<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n'
DDNS_Tool_v1 #46
`

Comment: Running Jenkins version 2.176.3